# ASP.NET - define controls in parent abstract usercontrol, but in children's markup?

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, user-controls, markup

I have abstract UserControlBase class inheriting from System.Web.UI.UserControl.
It only class, without markup, because I it's abstract base class.

Can I somehow define controls such as TextBoxes, DropDownLists etc. in this abstract base class, use them in methods, but markup define in children's usercontrol inherited from UserControlBase?

Pseudocode:

```
abstract UserControlBase : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private TextBox txt1;
    private DropDownList ddl1;

    private void test()
    {
          txt1.Text = "test";
          ddl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}

MyUserControl : UserControlBase
(markup):

<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the controls in base class protected, not private:

```
protected TextBox txt1;
protected DropDownList ddl1;
```

Also I suggest your UserControlBase is simple class (single *.cs file, no markup).

Comment: Oh, yes, my fault. They should be protected, not private.
UserControlBase is simple class (.cs).

What I'm dealing with is, how to join controls defined in parent base class with those in markup, because those in markup creates their own definition in MyUserControl.designer.cs class. I could delete it by hand, but I don't want to do it everytime I update MyUserControl markup.

Comment: Ok, here're the steps I'm following to prevent MyUserControl from creating its own definition of controls defined in UserControlBase: 1. Create new user control. 2. In *.cs file change its parent from UserControl to UserControlBase. 3. Add new TextBox in its markup and set its ID to txt1. 4. Save/build and look into *.designer.cs - it will NOT contain the definition for txt1.